# XDebug: is it possible to debug on remote host without "white" IP?

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug

One person ask me to fix the code on his server.
The problem is the software is very hard to install.

AFAIK xdebug.remote_connect_back requires *"white"* IP. Is it possible to debug PHP application without *white* IP on remote host?

Answer (score 0):

I found a very easy solution: [ssh tunnel](http://derickrethans.nl/debugging-with-xdebug-and-firewalls.html).